# How to run 32-bit app on 64-bit using VB 2005?

Tags: mysql, windows, vb.net, 32bit-64bit

I have an old app that i built on VB 2005 Express edition. Now i installed again the VB 2005 on my Windows 7 machine after 2-3 years. But when i run the app it freezes on my 64bit machine and still works fine with the 32bit. Is there a way to fix this so that i can run/debug my old app that was created using a 32bit VB 2005 Express?

Edit: I'm using MySQL 5.1( MySql.Data.MySqlClient ) Component.

Comment: 32 bit apps run perfectly on 64 bit. So, something is wrong with your application. Since we've no idea what your app is or does or how it's written, then we can't help you debug it.

Comment: it doesn't give any error every time i try to run it just freeze.

Comment: Time to do some debugging then. We are not magicians.

Comment: I added few details on the main component I'm using.

Comment: I cannot understand why you won't use the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already tried it, setting the Target CPU of the project to "x86" instead of "AnyCPU" may help.

This forces the application to run as a 32-bit application on all platforms instead of being run as a 64-bit application on 64-bit OS's.

Comment: I also came up on this solution but my problem here is how can i set the target CPU i can't find it on the Compile tab.

Comment: I don't have the express version to hand, but I seem to remember there being an option in the Tools -> Options menu that enables advanced build configurations.